# Winamp or equivalent scheduler

Tags: plugins, automation, winamp

I'm trying to find a good plug-in for winamp, or a similar program, that can act as a scheduler. After a thorough search on the winamp site, I haven't found anything suitable.

My main purposes are as follows:

1. To be able to play a specific list on a specified time, and hopefully with some kind of repetition. For example open an m3u on every monday at 17:00.
2. To encode some stream as an mp3 or wav, at a specified time. (That means, same as 1, but with different output plug-in, already installed, though I guess, that if there is no other choice, I can change the plug-in manually, but in this option, it is important that it stops recording automatically.

I have a plug-in which knows how to start and stop winamp playing, but it doesn't have an option to choose the file that plays, and that's not enough. Also I've seen suggestion to use windows scheduler, but it won't stop winamp, and won't change the plug-in if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what OS you are using, but this answer assumes it is Windows.

To play a specific playlist at a specific time you could set up a scheduled task.

You can pass arguments to the scheduled task, so you can pass in the path to the playlist.

I can't post screen shots at the moment, but under Windows 7 it's on "Actions" tab of Create Task. When you create the new action you specify the program name (in this case "C:\Program Files\Winamp\winamp.exe") then in the "Add arguments (optional):" field add the path to your playlist.

You set the time and day of when this task runs on the "Triggers" tab.

If you've got Winamp set to auto-repeat the playlist then you're good to go. You may even be able to set this on the arguments - check the command line arguments to Winamp.

Actually I've just spotted that you can specify the duration the task runs (at least in Windows 7). So if you want to record a stream you can specify the start time and how long you want the task to run for. I don't know how you tell Winamp to record though.

Comment: There's a standard output plug-in in winamp that outputs to file instead of speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your OS realy, I know you can pass winamp a file to run on startup, so you could use a shecduled task for this purpose.

Is there any reason why you want to use a plugin over a scheduled task?

Comment: As I've said, to stop recording, for example.